# Android: Back to tabhost instead the activity inside that

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-tabhost

I have a tabbed view (using TabActivity).  In each tab I have a different Activity, who forwards to another activities.

When I press the back button in any of the "secondary activities", it backs to activity in the tab, not to tabhost itselfs... I need to back to tabhost, not to activity on it...

Someone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that overriding the method OnRestart of my Activity that are on TabHost and defining a parameter who leads to Tabhost View or another Activity. Thank you!